# How to install nvidia graphic driver on optimus laptops?

Tags: cuda, driver, nvidia

I am trying to install cuda 7.5 toolkit on my laptop with Nvidia GeForce 555M graphic card. However, after I installed the driver and tried to reboot it. I could not into the system anymore. Everytime after I hit login, it went to a black screen, then come back again on the login screen. I guess this is because the GUI display is trying to use nvidia driver on intergrated  graphic card since this is an optimus laptop. Does anyone know how to install nvidia graphic driver on an optimus laptop for cuda computations? I will really appreaciate it if someone can help me out.I have been struggling on this for several days. Thanks!

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming or CUDA, and, thus an offtopic on StackOverflow. Refer to your operating system's documentation and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it many times and finally installed CUDA 7.5 on my laptop (Nvidia GeForce 750M) with optimus. It was very tricky but these steps worked for me.

**Step 1: Switch to kubuntu**. 
According to [this tutorial](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/NVIDIA-CUDA-GPU-computing-on-a-modern-laptop-629/), both Ubuntu Unity and Gnome3 desktops were very susceptible to black-screen states and/or corrupted workspaces. KDE didn’t seem to suffer from these problems. Following commands can help you to do the switch:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop build-essential emacs synaptic dkms
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

In my case after making sure Kubuntu working properly I removed the default ubuntu desktop by using

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
```

**Step 2: Install the nvidia driver for your graphics card.** NVidia 352.79 is the one I used. [Edit] I tried it myself. This step is actually optional. Skipping this step without any nvidia driver installed should also work.

**Step 3: Download and install [cuda toolkit deb local installer file](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)**. Because the .run installer did not work for me, I **strongly** recommend using the **deb** file.

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

**Step 4: Possible troubleshooting**.
During the installation(`sudo apt-get install cuda`), an error of unmet dependencies happened to me. I tracked down the problem and uninstalled the conflicting package by following this tutorial by @osdf [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/572910/514666).

**Step 5: Load module for CUDA**.
Run this command and you are hopefully free to use CUDA on your machine.

```
modprobe nvidia_uvm
```

If you encounter any issues, feel free to update your post or comment here. I will try to help.

Comment: Should I need to install nvidia driver before install cuda toolkit? The tutorial says to install the driver within cuda repo and don't install any other driver from different source.

Comment: @ZPeng  I would say yes. That did the trick for me. However, following the tutorial should theoretically also work. Just make sure you install **Nvidia 352.79** which is the one CUDA 7.5 is using.

Comment: OK. Now I get the driver working. But when I run tensorflow program using gpu setting, I encountered following error:

Comment: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:481] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_UNKNOWN ....  I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_init.cc:81] No GPU devices available on machine. It seems like the cuda cannot find my GPU when computing. Do you know why this is happening here? Is there a way I can fix it?

Comment: @ZPeng Glad you made it work. Did you test whether cuda works? Try this simple [helloworld](https://www.pdc.kth.se/resources/computers/historical-computers/zorn/how-to/how-to-compile-and-run-a-simple-cuda-hello-world) for cuda. If cuda works, then I reckon the problem lies on tensorflow side and you should better start a new question instead of trying to solve the different problem here. Sadly I personally have no experience with Tensorflow.

Comment: Thank you so much! Even though I didn't get tensorflow on GPU going, I get cuda installed correctly on my laptop. The only problem right now is that the cuda couldn't find my GPU unit. It's weird. Anyway, I probably just run tensorflow job on cpu then.